# Why greedy plus behaves different than star?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

With * and + greedies behaves different in the below regexp patterns, why?

This is my text:

`hello abcdef ghijklmc happiness<span>Lorem impsum</span> lorem
<p>Lorem impsum</p>Lorem impsum Today is Feb 23rd, 2003`

**This is regexp:**

`<[/]?[a-z].*?>`

**Result:**

[image]

**With this pattern:**

`<[/]?[a-z].+?>`

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Please [for the love of god](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1348195) don't parse HTML with regular expressions. It will give you a world of pain and the DOM already contains _extremely_ powerful methods to work with HTML directly.

Comment: `+?` and `*?` are not greedy quantifiers but the opposite - they are "lazy" or "reluctant".

Answer (score 5):

Because `*` is **0 or more** and `+` is **1 or more**.

When the tag name only has one character in it:

1. `[a-z]` matches the `p`
2. `.` matches the `>`

   - If you have a `+` the `>` has to be matched by the `.` to it keeps matching until the next `>` (at the end of the next tag)
   - If you have a `*`, the `>` doesn't have to be matched by the `.` (since you can have 0 matches) so the `>` matches that character instead.
3. The `>` matches the next `>`